# React router useHistory

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want when I press on the button it redirects me to the payment page.

```
import React,{useHistory, useState} from 'react'
import data from './data.json'
function GLC() {

    let history = useHistory();
    function handleClick() {
        history.push("/payment");
      }

    return (
        <div  >
        {data.map((postData) =>{
            console.log(postData)
            return(
            <div key= 
            {postData.id}>
           <div className='absolute '> 
            <img className='w-screen object-contain'src="./ModImages/Gclass.jpg"></img>         
            <h1 className='absolute ml-24 md:text-5xl sm:text-5xl  top-8'>Class G</h1>
            <h1 className='absolute text-base font-mono  ml-24 top-24'>$43,600</h1> 
            <button onClick={handleClick} className=' absolute text-black-600 h-10 top-24 ml-24 mt-32 bg- 
             white w-36 rounded-full focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-gray-600'>BuyNow</button>

           </div>
           </div>
            )
        })
        }
    </div>                
    )
}

export default GLC
```

Comment: And what happens with your current code?

Comment: @jonrsharpe when I click on the GLC component I get this TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Comment: `useHistory` needs to be imported from react-router, not react. Ie: `import { useHistory } from 'react-router'`

Comment: I am blind thank you man

Comment: @Nicholas Tower Can I ask you something

Answer (score 0):

```
// Make sure you alreadly installed the react-router-dom package.
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';


function GLC() {
   const history = useHistory();

   function handleClick() {
      history.push("/payment");
   }

   // ...
}
```

Then you can work .